# how to extend the width size with out using height using css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Here i'm using `material-ui` i want to fix the full video width in the screen. i used `width:auto`  and attached a below image ,can any one please help me . how to fix this thanks in advance

[image]

this is my code:-

```
    <Row className="waitingVideo">
        <Col xs={3} className="waitingRoom">
           <WaitingRoom customerList={waitingRoom} accept={accept} chat={chat} reject={reject}></WaitingRoom>
               <Accordion className={classes.customers}>
                  <AccordionSummary
                      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                      aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                      id="panel1a-header">
                      <Typography className={classes.heading}>customer 1</Typography>
                      <ChatIcon className={classes.chat} onClick={chat}></ChatIcon>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <AccordionDetails>
                     <Typography>Lorem gkfgs shfksk sfkugsk sfkugs hfgsek</Typography>
                  </AccordionDetails>
                  </Accordion>
                  <Accordion>
                  <AccordionSummary
                     expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                     aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                     id="panel1a-header">
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>customer 2</Typography>
                    <ChatIcon className={classes.chat} onClick={chat}></ChatIcon>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                        <Typography>Lorem gkfgs shfksk sfkugsk sfkugs hfgsek</Typography>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                    </Accordion>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={9}>
                    <video  meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" id="localVideo" width="auto"  autoPlay playsInline controls={false} muted={true}/> 
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

Comment: Then, why don't you use width:100% to cover the whole `col xs={9}` width ? Or do you want to cover the whole page? Then why nest it inside a col xs={9} ? Not really sure what you actually want to achieve

Comment: i just edited the image , if i use width:100% the page is scrolling

Comment: Well it's scrolling because in order to keep the aspect ratio of the video, the height increases as well. If you increase the width and don't increase the height, your video would look awful

Comment: is there any way to only extend width ,but not height

Comment: Well, why would you want to do that ? :) The video will look awful. Anyway, try `width:100%; height:100%;max-height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `height: 100vh` to use only the viewable height of the window.  If you need to trim it down for other content on screen, you can use `calc(100vh - 80px)`.